# Geany GTK Cursor Thickness

Tags: gtk, geany

How can I change the mouse cursor color and thickness in Geany (or GTK)?  I'm talking about the cursor that is controlled by the mouse only, not the cursor that is at the current location within the text.  See attached snapshot -- the mouse-cursor is very small and difficult to see (it's actually worse than the snapshot).  This is true for all Themes within Geany.  I think the answer lies within gtkrc, so I'm hoping somebody that knows GTK can get this quickly.  I'm using Geany on Windows, so I think I need to find just the right GTK property within ...\Geany\share\themes\MS-Windows\gtk-2.0\gtkrc
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**On Linux:**

First of all, you should download a theme package and extract all in a directory. Then, you should paste it in the " /home/saeed/.config/geany/filedefs" path.

Goto above path and type following commands:

```
chmod +x install.sh

./install
```

Goto View -> Change Color Scheme

And choose a theme

> press F11 to view fullscreen forever

**On Windows:**

Copy theme config files into "%appdata%\geany\colorschemes"

Goto View -> Change Color Scheme

And choose a theme

**Reference:**

https://github.com/geany/geany-themes/

Also, you can search other themes in the internet.